# TinyMCE or WordPress inserting WBR html element into text in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tinymce, shortcode

Greeting all,

I've written a [simple WordPress shortcode](http://github.com/northk/hid-showcode/blob/master/hid-showcode.php) which wraps inline `$content` in `<code>` tags. I see that sometimes the `$content` contains `<wbr />` elements, which must be inserted either by TinyMCE or by WordPress. I'd never even heard of `<wbr />` (word break opportunity) until I [looked it up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr).

I'm guessing that TinyMCE is inserting the element in the WordPress visual editor, but I can't be sure. I looked through both the WordPress and TinyMCE source and I see mentions of `<wbr />` but I couldn't find where it is being injected into the post content.

Do you know why the `<wbr />` elements are being inserted, and if it's possible to turn off that behavior in shortcodes?

Forgot to mention that (for now) I'm working around the issue by removing the `<wbr />` elements using `preg_replace()`. But I consider this kind of hack-ish and I'd prefer to turn it off in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

You can set invalid elements in tinymce using the [invalid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3ainvalid_elements) option. This will take care of your issue. You have a lot of control with tinymce, you shouldn't have to use any regex. This and similar options in the cleanup/output should help you.

```
tinymce.init({
        ...
        invalid_elements : "wbr"
});
```